# Why use backup if icloud is already enabled for every application

Tags: icloud, backup

iCloud Backup refers to Settings > [name] > iCloud > iCloud Backup and iCloud sync refers to iCloud > *Apps using iCloud* and you enable/disable iCloud for the respective applications. Have a look at this [image] for reference.

I found the image online.

I am not sure if that enable/disable for the apps (the ones displayed like Mail, Contacts, Calendars, etc) works only if the iCloud Backup is enabled.

Comment: "your accounts, documents, Health data, Home configuration, and settings", as the Backup message says, seems distinct from any of the apps listed for which you can enable iCloud, so it's presumably backing up other types of data.

Answer (score 12):

Most of what iCloud does (other than iCloud Backup) is synchronize data between your various devices and the cloud. [Synchronization is not a backup!](https://gigaom.com/2010/03/26/syncing-does-not-a-backup-make/) Synchronization protects you in case a device is lost, fails, etc, but does nothing to protect against data being deleted or corrupted. If you delete or overwrite an important note on one of your devices, iCloud sync will promptly delete/overwrite the copy on the iCloud servers, and then do the same on all your other devices. In a situation like this, a backup would let you go back to before the problem happened, but sync copies the problem around.

(As Allan pointed out, it's best to have multiple "redundant" backups -- a sync service doesn't count as one of them.)

Comment: That's my favourite point to make: good synchronization services that sync your file changes quickly are *ideal* in making sure that if you accidentally mess something up, it's messed up *everywhere* at the speed of *c l o u d*

Answer (score 6):

There’s an old adage in IT regarding backups - if it doesn’t exist in 3 different places, it doesn’t exist.

iClould backup is just one backup for your iOS device.  Ok, but you only use your iOS device with iCloud.  True, but backups get corrupted - all the time!  Having a second backup ensures that there are two different places you can get to if something disasterous happens.  Like your Internet goes down (no access to iCloud backup) and your iPhone crashed and you need to restore.  Having a local backup would easily solve that problem.

Three places?  Sure!  You have a document on local on your iPhone, on your iCloud drive, backed up to iCloud makes three.  Having it backed up locally makes four places to gain access to that document.

Backups are one of those things that you take for granted until you really need it.  I’ve never seen anyone complain that they had too many backups when their hard drive crashed or device was stolen.  I’ve only seen people in despair when they didn’t have any.

Answer (score -1):

Most people do not understand how iCloud actually works. Let’s clear it up.

There are two spaces iCloud uses: the backup space and the sync space. The switches in the “Apps Using iCloud” determine which space your data is going to. On, that data is stored in the Sync space. Off, that data is in the backup. This is important to understand. It **does not** indicate whether data is being stored in iCloud or not.

You want all of your data in the sync space. Why? If a software restore ever needs to be done to eliminate a software issue from your device, you don’t want to restore anything from the backup. The backup contains system configuration data that will match your device, including any embedded software problems that have cropped up over time. Restoring from the backup will bring those problems right back into the device.

I never recommend backup restores anymore, unless you are not currently experiencing any issues. Even then, I recommend letting any new device have its own unique system config data. Always restore factory software from a Mac.

[If you forgot your iPhone passcode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)

Then, when setting up, choose the “Don’t Transfer Anything” option. It’s misleading wording because iCloud will download everything in the Sync space to your device. You can look in the “Purchased” section of your App Store account to quickly reinstall all your third-party apps.

This is the best way to achieve a minimum of software issues on an Apple device.

Comment: Not all applications sync their data via iCloud, how does your approach backup their settings and data?

Comment: Whatever apps don’t use iCloud usually have their own system, or it’s not really critical to store their settings. The method I described is how software issues are eliminated from devices, so I recommend getting in the habit of setting up every new device like this. I’ve actually contacted a few developers to support syncing to avoid the backup problems.

Comment: I can think of quite some apps which neither use iCloud nor have their own backup, and rely on the iOS backup. Also, login credentials are only included in an encrypted backup, not sure how much fun it is to re-login all apps if required. Agreed, avoiding full backups may help to avoid problems caused by long-forgotten settings, but there is a significant risk of data loss.